# Material design Bootstrap not working in angular

Tags: angular, uicomponents, material-design-bootstrap

I'm new to angular, installed angularCLI and mdb bootstrap by following the steps from [this link](https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/angular/getting-started/quick-start/).
When tried to run a example from [here](https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/angular/navigation/navbar/). The styling didn't appear only the blank HTML list with absolutely no design was executed. How to solve this issue?

Comment: Did you include the required imports in `app.module.ts` file?

Comment: yes, I have entered as per the instruction on the above link